# Simple slideshow with jQuery and css3

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I want to create a simple fade-in / fade-out slideshow by using css animation and jquery as a fallback. I added a scale css transform to the animation so the slide will slowly zooming in  until it's replaced by next slide

This is the HTML

```
<ul class="fadein">
  <li style="background-image:url('http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg');"></li>
  <li style="background-image:url('http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg');"></li>
  <li style="background-image:url('http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg');"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the css

```
ul.fadein { display:block;position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; }
ul.fadein li { display:block; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-size: cover;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}

/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {

        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {

        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {

        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {

        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {

        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {

        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {

        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {

        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {  }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {

        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {

        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {

        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {

        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {  }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {

        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {

        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {

        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {

        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {

        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {

        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {

        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {

        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {  }
}
```

and this is the javascript

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('ul.fadein li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery('ul.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('li').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('ul.fadein');
        },
      5000);
});
```

It works good unless the slide background size back to original size before it fades out, so the transition doesn't look good.
I have put the script in http://jsfiddle.net/kzc6sp08/

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: have you tried fading out with css itself?

Comment: I did, but no luck :\

Comment: how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kzc6sp08/2/)?

Comment: it looks good but the images are not cross-fade :(